# Can Lists/ArrayLists hold primitive types in VB and C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, list, arraylist

My AP Computer Science class just learned about ArrayLists in Java today. In Java, ArrayLists cannot hold a primitive data type without a wrapper class. Is the same true with VB and C#? Would this be valid:

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net has feature called "[boxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)" that takes care of this for you with `ArrayList` by creating a wrapper object behind the scenes. For `List<T>` .Net is able to handle the primitive types directly without boxing or wrapper objects, and it's one of several reasons `List<T>` is strongly preferred over `ArrayList` when working with .Net code.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I do like Lists better.